# 500 error "nextLink value without skip or skiptoken" delta API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to track changes on a sharepoint drive but I got an obscure error message.

Here my call:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{direvId}/root/delta`

And here the response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "nextLink value without skip or skiptoken",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-03T16:38:03",
            "request-id": "4cb9de13-817d-47c7-a0b3-2605470789b9",
            "client-request-id": "4cb9de13-817d-47c7-a0b3-2605470789b9"
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue?

EDIT:
The issue is releated to the application access token.

Comment: Can you repro the issue with Graph Explorer or POSTMAN (outside of your code) as well?

Comment: Hello, I'm getting this error using Postman

Comment: I tried the above api call with POSTMAN and tried accessing Ondrive for business. But i failed to repro the issue.

Comment: Have you tried accessing Onedrive for business or personal?

Comment: It's Onedrive for bussiness. I also tried to use another sharepoint site but the result is the same. To reproduce the issue you have to use an application access token. Using a delegated access token for the same endpoint, the call is working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the issue. Using postman and having the header **Prefer** set as follow `Prefer: apiversion=2.1` was causing the 500 error.
With no Prefer header set or using the headers suggested in the documentation everything is working as expected.[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#scanning-permissions-hierarchies)